# Set image changes when I move from one fragment to another, How to keep it forever even when I restart the app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-imageview

please help I could not add code, it is throwing error , I'm new.

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> picActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
    new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
    new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
            if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Intent data = result.getData();
                // your operation....
                Uri pic = data.getData();
                profile.setImageURI(pic);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the device's android version. If it's 10 or lower than that, then you can simply save the file path in the `Sharedpreference` so you can access it later and load the image from there (You can do it in android 10 with `requestLegacyExternalStorage` of course or you can go with the 2nd option which I provided below).

But, if you're writing the code for android 11 or higher, then there are only three standard ways to do it.

**1. Using SAF (Storage Access Framework) :-**

You can get the storage access permission of that perticular folder everytime you pick an image from there. But this is not the best option when your app is doing it multiple times. (what if it's photo editor app or social media or something like that?!)

**2. Manage all files permission :-**

You can go with the `All files access` permission but it's also too much for the small task and you also have to give clarification to google play when your  app has that permission. So it's also the very last option.

**3. Accessing from internal app directories - THE BEST WAY! :-**

You can go with this option with almost every app!
All you have to do is just take read storage permission, access the file using `file descriptor`, write it to the internal app directory (it can be either external files directory or cache directory), then you'll have a lifetime access of the image. You can save the path to `Sharedpreference` and access it anytime.

If you want to save edited image to the gallery then it will also be easy because you already have both read and write permission to that image saved in internal app directory.

That's it. I know the answer is lengthy but it's worth it. :)